# Images not loading on Angular Application

Tags: angular, web-deployment

I've built and deployed an Angular App using the build command on the cli with the deploy-url option as below:

`ng b -deploy-url /portal/`

And my scripts work which is great but everything in the assets folder is showing the console as 404 not found. I assumed that the deploy url option would have fixed this as well as the scripts? When I inspect the element in the console the url doesn't seem to have the '/portal/' in front of it.

```
<img _ngcontent-c0="" alt="User Avatar" id="user-avatar" src="../assets/users/profile/WebDevelopWolf.png">
```

So I assume it's looking for the assets folder in the wrong place? In which case I'm not sure what it will need to find the folder that also won't break my local test where it's just served up using a straight `ng serve` command.

Just in case it's relevant, I've deployed this to a Windows 2016 server as an app.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the favicon can't be found either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give relative path

```
src="assets/users/profile/WebDevelopWolf.png"
```

Angular always points to assets folder provided in angular.json.

Comment: Yes it will. Regardless of ng serve or ng build, the assets folder is always the same. But this can be configured in angular.json